# html div going behind img

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make this layout (many of these are in a list):

An image (of varying height, but a set width) on the left. To the right is an `<h2>`, and below that, but still to the right of the image is a div with other content in it.

The div is used to provide a different colored background.  Right now, the div for some reason extends behind the image, and the images has a varying distance between them, and sometimes one element will get pushed to the right by the height of the image above.

http://jsfiddle.net/RQsUc/

Comment: it looks like you need clear: left; somewhere, but could you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: that's not html... posting your actual markup would be helpful.

Comment: You will want to read up on clear. http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspclear.htm

Comment: added a jsFiddle.  Id never heard of it before, cool though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your outermost `div`s (*`div (display: block)`*) to [contain the floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

Comment: This fixed the problem with the images next to each other

Comment: So, what are the remaining problem(s)?

Comment: Sorry, that actually did fix it, I just applied it to the wrong div.  Thanks!